# Trying to find the angle that intersects a point along the hypotenuse

Tags: trigonometry

How can I find the angle of a right triangle with origin 0,0 where the hypotenuse length is known (e.g. 6), and a specific point (e.g. 3,1) is intersected by that hypotenuse?

So in the example below, how would I solve for the possible angles of theta? I would want the one with the largest angle.

My trigonometry is pretty rusty so please use simple explanations, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You should add what you have done in the questions. Anyway, in the example above, there are 4 solutions to theta, so we need another bound, such as another length of the triangle, or another point on the hypotenuse.

Comment: I would want to get the highest angle possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ be the lengths of the other sides.

Then, using Thales' theorem (draw the vertical from the point $P(3,1)$),

$$\frac{x-3}{x}=\frac{1}{y}$$

And with Pythagoras' theorem,

$$x^2+y^2=36$$

And we are interested in the value of $t=\dfrac yx=\tan\theta$.

We have

$$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{1}{x-3}$$

Hence

$$x=3+\frac1t$$

And

$$1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}=\frac{36}{x^2}$$

Hence

$$x^2=\frac{36}{1+t^2}$$

Therefore

$$(3+\frac1t)^2=\frac{36}{1+t^2}$$

Which simplifies to

$$9t^4+6t^3-26t^2+6t+1=0$$

Numerically, there are two positive solutions for $t$ ($0.3846003073, 1.206507801$), and each one yields a valid $(x,y)$ pair.

Intuitively we could expect two solutions: imagine a segment of length $6$, that is initially along the $y$ axis. And move one end of this segment along the $x$ axis, while the other end stays on the $y$ axis. If there is a solution at all, the segment will once get through the point $P(3,1)$, then it will be *above* $P$, and while the segment continues its movement, it has to pass through $P$ a second time in order for the segment to ultimately lie the $x$ axis (hence *below* $P$).

Comment: You’ve definitely  understood what I’m asking. I came to the same intuitive conclusion (there will always be two answers), but I don’t know enough algebra to solve for t in your answer.

Comment: @JesseBarnum There is a formula (equations of degree $4$ are solvable by radicals), but it's really not practical. That's why I gave you the numerical values. There are also two negative solutions, that can't work as $\tan\theta>0$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

> Set the point of the triangle on the y-axis as $(0,y)$, and call this length $y$. Do the same for the other side.

> Use the Pythagorean Theorem to get a Diophantine Equation.

> Now use the slope formula from to points to find the slope of $(0,y)$ and $(x,0)$.  Now use it again on the $(3,1)$ on both sides to give you more equations.

> Now solve the simultaneous equations.

> For the largest angle, find the case where $x$ is the smallest value.